# Page Analytics Chrome Extension questions

Tags: analytics

I am new to stackoverflow and was hoping someone could help with the following questions about page analytics Google Chrome Extension:

- Does the page analytics extension have a user interface for end users?
- Does the page analytics have a user interface for administrator?
- Does the page analytics extension have a command line interface for users and/or administrators?
- Does it require any client side installation?
- And lastly, does page analytics send/receive data? If so what data would be sent is it secure, does to a cloud, etc

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. Please take a look to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This site is mostly about programming, and also about tools used for programming. That does not mean that you always have to provide some code that is not working or anything like that. Generic questions like this one could be valid -although honestly I'm not so sure about this one, unless you modify it. In my opinion, you are asking a lot of questions as if you were about to decide if you install the extension or not. I would suggest you read some tutorials, you install it, and then...

Comment: ... if you have more concrete questions about it you post them. This is just too broad as it is. Thanks.